# Como mandar um email no formato RTF usando EWS?

Tags: c#

Quero mandar um e mail no formato RTF(Rich Text Format) usando a API EWS(Exchange Web Service)

```
  ExtendedPropertyDefinition RtfCompressed = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x1009, MapiPropertyType.Binary); 

                    PropertySet propSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, EmailMessageSchema.Subject, RtfCompressed);

                    EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.Bind(wsExchange, emailID,propSet);
```

Gostaria de saber se são esses parametros mesmo que passo para os objetos das classes ExtendedPropertyDefinition e PropertySet

Comment: Também preciso disso